How can I force all connections to be HTTP (not HTTPS)?
I'm hosting a simple blog and don't want to pay for a certificate to match the domain name.
When users go to the blog their browsers are defaulting to HTTPS so they get an ugly certificate name mismatch error (the web app appears to be given a *.azurewebsites.com certificate)
I've disabled HTTPS redirection, however I basically want the opposite, if someone goes to https://blog.com/ I want them to be redirected to http://blog.com/, how can this be done via Azure Portal?


I'm hosting a simple blog and don't want to pay for a certificate to match the domain name.

Certificates are free now, and have been since 2019.
